# how to inject two mockito object in single Implentaion class

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mocking, mockito, junit5

Right now only one mocking working fine. another one returning null pointer exception. Both @Autowired and @Mock giving nullpointer for BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

### My Test class

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class UserServiceTests {
    
    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @InjectMocks
    private UserService userService =new UserServiceImpl();
    
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception{
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
}
```

### My Implementaiton class

[image]

Comment: show more about your test class configuration such as if it is a @SpringBootTest or just a plain mockito test etc

Comment: updated the question , check now

Comment: Please don't post images of the code. Add the code instead to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This code may be work for you. You cannot use `@Autowire` in this case. Now, you don't need have to mock the function of `BCryptPasswordEncoder`

```java
public class UserServiceTests {
    
    @InjectMocks
    private UserService userService;
    
    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Spy
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception{
        passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to unit test your `UserServiceImpl` class, just drop the `@SpringBootTest` (which is actually a fully-fledged integration test). The following should work as intended:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class UserServiceTests {
    
    @Mock
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @InjectMocks
    private UserServiceImpl userService;

    // Your tests
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no default instance of `BCryptPasswordEncoder` that can be injected. So you can't autowire it. You should declare a Bean for that somewhere in your configs or any other place.
Example:

```java
@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Comment: This one alrready there in my configuration class 

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

Answer (score 0):

This one working for me

```java
public class UserServiceTests {
    
    @InjectMocks
    private UserService userService = new UserServiceImpl();
    
    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Mock
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception{
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `@SpringBootTest` and then mock everything? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: ahh ok , updated now